# ¿Como introducir una variable en una expresión regular?

Tags: javascript, expresion, regular

Tengo una variable simple de cadena:

```
var saludo="Hola, ¿Cómo estás?";
```

Ahora deseo detectar si se encuentra la palabra "ola"sin importar combinación de mayúsculas o minúsculas. Lo logro fácil usando una expresión regular:

```
saludo.match(/olA/gi)
```

Bien, ahora si deseo que la palabra a "buscar" sea por medio de una variable entonces la pregunta es: ¿Cómo lo hago?

He intentando hacer esto:

```
saludo.match(/+variable+/gi)
```

Pero me marca error, o también intente esto:

```
saludo.match("/"+variable+'/')
```

Me marca error

```
¿Cómo se puede introducir una variable en una expresión regular?
```

Comment: Es requisito hacerlo por regex? porque hay otros métodos que ya están pensados para hacer eso... Solo para estar claro de la pregunta.

Comment: Pues...creo que al final lo que se busca es el objetivo de usar la expresión regular para localizar una palabra mediante una variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa sintaxis se llama [Regular Expresión](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Puedes crear una utilizando new [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)(variable), Ejemplo

```js
var saludo="Hola, ¿Cómo estás?";
var Exp = new RegExp('olA','gi');
var result = saludo.match(Exp);
console.log(result);
```